# BASH awk outputs on the same line with for loop?

Tags: bash, awk

Trying to get outputs on the same line then do LOW AVG MAX Read output.

This is my function:

```
perform_hdparm() {
for i in {1..5}; do hdparm -t "$1"; done | 
    awk '/seconds/ {print $11}' }
```

The For Loop:

```
for drive in ${hddletter[@]}; do
printf '%s: %s\n' "$drive" "$(perform_hdparm "$drive")"
```

I have it doing FIVE test and the results are coming out the following:

```
/dev/sdc: 202.69
203.05
203.06
203.20
203.03
```

So what I want is the following:

```
/dev/sdc: 202.69 203.05 203.06 203.20 203.03 LOW: 203.03 HIGH: 203.20 AVG: 203.006
```

Thank you

Comment: Remove `\n` from `printf` format?

Comment: @devnull I got the same results =\

Comment: @devnull the newline in the `printf` statement comes after all of the undesired newlines. The problem is the `print` statement used in awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do everything in Awk.

```
perform_hdparm() {
    for i in {1..5}; do hdparm -t "$1"; done | 
    awk -v drive="$1" '/seconds/ {a[++i]=$11}
        END { printf "%s:", drive;
            for(j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                s+=a[j]; printf " %f", a[j];
                if (j==1) min=max=a[j];
                else {
                    if (a[j]>max) max=a[j];
                    if (a[j]<min) min=a[j];
                }
            }
            printf "min: %f max: %f avg: %f\n", min, max, s/i; }'
}

for drive in ${hddletter[@]}; do
    perform_hdparm "$drive"
done
```

Comment: I am getting the following error on your code:

`awk: cmd. line:10:             printf "min: %f max: %f avg: %f\n", min, max, s/j; }
awk: cmd. line:10:                                                                 ^ unexpected newline or end of string
`

Comment: @user3533305 I think the problem was an unclosed `}`, I've edited the answer.

Comment: @TomFenech That worked and thank you both! The output is the following: 
`/dev/sdf: 190.120000 190.570000 190.850000 191.080000 200.980000min: 190.120000 max: 200.980000 avg: 160.600000
`

A lot more zeros but that is ok.

Comment: @TomFenech Where is a good site to read up on awk command? I would like to learn a lot more about it.

Comment: @user3533305 if you want to reduce the number of zeroes, change the format specifier `%f` to `%.Nf`, where `N` is the number of decimal places you want.

Comment: @TomFenech Just realized the avg is not giving me the avg. `/dev/sdf: 190.14 190.63 190.06 190.53 191.08 min: 190.06 max: 191.08 avg: 158.74` The avg for this should be 190.488 (Add them up then divide by count) not 158.74

Comment: @user3533305 note that this isn't my answer, and calculating the min, max or average wasn't part of the original question. I answered the original question, which was about avoiding newlines in your output.

Comment: @tripleee It seems the avg is not calculating out right. Without all the min, max, etc. I can get the avg by using this `awk '/seconds/ { total += $11; count++ } END { print (total / count) }'`

Comment: Awk is simple enough that you could do a second tutorial if you don't like the first. [The Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk%20tutorial) look reasonable to me.

Comment: I think I found the problem but I'm not in a place where I can test the fix. See the edit history.

Comment: @tripleee That fix worked, I did notice that `j` was bringing back `6` then being divided by `s`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `print` in awk uses the output record separator (`ORS`), which is a newline by default. If you want a space instead you can change it:

```
awk -v ORS=" " '/seconds/ {print $11}'
```

or use `printf` instead, which means that you can choose the format yourself:

```
awk '/seconds/ {printf "%s ", $11}'
```

This will print each of the numbers, separating them with a space rather than the output record separator.

Comment: This worked, I used the `awk '/seconds/ {printf "%s ", $11}'` Ah, something so simple, didn't even thought about the print VS. printf.

Comment: @user3533305 glad you got it sorted :)